# How to convert Json to JsobObject on android

Tags: java

I have a json structure like this:

```
[{
    "name": "test",
    "urlImg": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "urlLink": "test",
}]
```

And I want to retrieve the 4 values, I tried with:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
name = jsonObj.getString("TAG_TITLE");
```

I correctly download the json but name doesn't retrieve anything.. Am I parsing it wrong?

Comment: because its an array, you have to get he first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is array `[...]` with one object `{..}`. So you need to

1. create `JSONArray`
2. get its only `JSONObject`
3. read its properties

Comment: ok.. but I can't understand how.. I tried with contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("name");

But then how do I parse what's inside contacts (that is an array)?

Comment: Based on your code example you should try with something more like `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr); JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0); String name = obj.getString("name");`.

Comment: I don't have Android installed so I can't help you with proper code, but idea should be same for all parsers.